# C# commandline parser : produces BadFormatConversionError when a bool option is given without value

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

I'm trying to specify a flag using the [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) library

```
[Option('d', "content", Required = false,  HelpText = "<Content file>\n (Mandatory) Path to the content file.")]
public String? ContentFile { get; set; }

[Option('e', "extend", Required = false, Default = false, HelpText = "Whether it is an extend operation or not")]
 public bool? Extend { get; set; }
```

Execution command
\a.exe   **--extend** --content kdssign.deps.json

If I move "--extend" to end then Execption is not thrown but still Extend varaible is not set.

My Expectation is iff --extend is provided from command line then it should be set without waiting for any value to be provided.

Comment: Are you sure the flag isn't set to the type's default, ie `null`? Have you tried with `public bool Extend`? After all, if the absence of the flag means it's `false`, the property should never be null. BTW [the Quickstart example](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline#quick-start-examples) uses `public bool Verbose { get; set; }` with the `Required=false` to specify a flag. `false` is already the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `public bool Extend { get; set; }` instead of `bool?`. Flags in CommandLineParser are supported through `bool` properties. If the flag is missing, the property will be false by default. A `bool?` on the other hand can have *three* values: the default null, true or false.

The [library's quickstart example](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline#quick-start-examples) shows how to use a flag:

```
public class Options
{
    [Option('v', "verbose", Required = false, HelpText = "Set output to verbose messages.")]
    public bool Verbose { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
           .WithParsed<Options>(o =>
           {
               if (o.Verbose)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine($"Verbose output enabled. Current Arguments: -v {o.Verbose}");
                   Console.WriteLine("Quick Start Example! App is in Verbose mode!");
               }
               else
               {
                   Console.WriteLine($"Current Arguments: -v {o.Verbose}");
                   Console.WriteLine("Quick Start Example!");
               }
           });
}
```